# Boolean Algebra: Simplifying $\;xyz + x'y + xyz'$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Given the following expression: $xyz + x'y + xyz'\,$ where ($'$) means complement, I tried to simplify it by first factoring out a y so I would get $\;y(xz + x' + xz').\,$

At this point, it appears I have several options:

A) Use two successive rounds of distributive property:

$\begin{align} y( (x + x')(z + x') + xz') ) 
&= y ( z + x' + xz')\\ & = y ( z + (x' + x)(x' + z') )\\ &= y ( z + x' + z') \\ &= y ( x') \\ &= yx'\end{align}$

B) Or I could use absorption,

$\begin{align}y ( xz + xz' + x' ) 
&= y ( x (z+z') + x') \\
& = y ( x + x' )\\
&= y ( 1) \\ 
&= y\end{align}$

I believe the second answer is correct. What am I doing wrong with option A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For option A, you made the error of stating $x' +1 = x'$ when its really $x' + 1 = 1$. Hence you would get the same answer for both options.

Comment: Oh, I see the error. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Using the distributive property (first method), we get:

$$\begin{align} xyz + x'y + xyz' & = xy(z +  z') + x'y \\ &= xy + x'y \\&= (x + x')y \\&= y\end{align}$$

You erred when you went from $ y ( z + x' + z') $ to $yx'$. You should have $$y((z+z')+x')= y(1+x') = y\cdot 1 = y$$

Answer (score 0):

Second answer is correct as can also be done as follows
\begin{align}
xyz+x^{\prime}y+xyz^{\prime}&=xyz+xyz^{\prime}+x^{\prime}y\qquad\text{commutative law}\\&=xy(z+z^{\prime})+x^{\prime}y\\&=xy.1+x^{\prime}y\\&=(x+x^{\prime})y=1.y=y
\end{align}
While as in A) Note that 
\begin{align}
y((x+x^{\prime})(z+x^{\prime})+xz^{\prime})&=y(z+x^{\prime}+xz^{\prime})\\&=yz+x^{\prime}y+xyz^{\prime}\neq xyz+x^{\prime}y+xyz^{\prime}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

xyz + x'y + xyz'=

multiplying (z+z') in x'y = x'y(z+z')=x'y
            z+z'=1 (do a truth table)

xyz + x'y(z+z') + xyz'

xyz + (x'yz + x'yz') + xyz'

take common

(xyz + x'yz) +( x'yz' + xyz')

{((yz(x+x'))  +  (yz'(x+x')) }

yz+yz'

y(z+z')

:Y

Comment: Please use MathJax